# Why is $\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 f(\frac{x_1 + \ldots + x_n}{n})dx_1\ldots dx_n = E[f(\frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n})]$

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reviewing some old homework in probability theory and I encountered the following exercise. We computed $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 f\left(\frac{x_1 + \ldots + x_n}{n}\right)dx_1\ldots dx_n$$ for any continuous and bounded function $f$.

Since we have to use methods of probability theory we can replace the integral by the expected value

$$E[f\left(\frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n}\right)]$$

while $X_i$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.

Afterwards, we can simply apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, the continuity property of $f$ and law of large numbers to find the limit of $f(1/2)$.

My problem is to remember *why* we can replace the integral by the expected value $E$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]^n$ hence, for every measurable function $g$,
$$
\mathbb E(g(X_1,\ldots,X_n))=\iint_{[0,1]^n}g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mathrm dx_1\ldots\mathrm dx_n.
$$
Now, apply this fact to the function
$$
g:(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto f\left(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}n\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! How could I miss that.